# R Curl Post Form

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I want to post a form and use returning data.

Page I wanna get data is:
http://www.bigpara.com/analiz/mali-tablolar/

```
assetscrap <- function(sirket){
  a <- postForm("http://www.bigpara.com/analiz/mali-tablolar/",
    Yil = "2013", Donem = "4", Kur = "TL", Cins = "1", Submit = "Getir",
    HisseKod = sirket);
  a <- htmlParse(a);
  span <- xpathSApply(a, "//div[@class='maliTable']//li//span", xmlValue);
  small <- xpathSApply(a, "//div[@class='maliTable']//li//small", xmlValue);
  small <- gsub("[.]","",small);
  small <- as.numeric(small);
  cikti <- data.table(span, small);
  cikti <- cikti[cikti$span == "AKTİF TOPLAMI" | cikti$span == "A K T İ F T O P L A M I"];
  cikti <- cikti[order(-small)];
  cikti <- cikti[1,]$small;
}
```

for ex. when I run `assetscrap("FROTO")` function it returns

```
* About to connect() to www.bigpara.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 83.66.15.71... * connected
* Connected to www.bigpara.com (83.66.15.71) port 80 (#0)
> POST /analiz/mali-tablolar/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Host: www.bigpara.com
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.bigpara.com/analiz/mali-tablolar/
Content-Length: 627
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------b1006fa82edf

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Length: 182029
< Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCCTSBQAT=HOOCGCIBDPNEJMFGGFGGHNPM; path=/
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Sat, 06 Dec 2014 14:00:12 GMT
< Set-Cookie: NSC_cjhqbsb_iuuq_WJQ=ffffffff504a9f5645525d5f4f58455e445a4a42367f;Version=1;path=/;httponly

< 
* Connection #0 to host www.bigpara.com left intact
```

What's the thing I'm overlooking? I think I'm doing everything correctly but server doesnt respond my request

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say the server does not respond? You're getting a status 200 (OK), and a response length of 182,000 bytes??

The POST request is working fine. Your problem is in the line:

```
cikti <- cikti[cikti$span == "AKTİF TOPLAMI" | cikti$span == "A K T İ F T O P L A M I"];
```

which is returning 0 rows. Several things wrong here:

First, the text in the `span` column has mixed encoding:

```
head(Encoding(span),20)
#  [1] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"  
#  [9] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown"
# [17] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown"
```

You can fix this by using

```
span  <- iconv(span,from="UTF-8",to="")
```

right after you extract the `span` strings.

Second, your second condition: `cikti$span == "A K T İ F T O P L A M I"` does not exist in `cikti`. There are 3 spaces between the words, e.g., `"A K T İ F   T O P L A M I"`.

Third, data.tables are not data frames. it is very bad practice to use, e.g.,

```
cikti <- cikti[cikti$span == "AKTİF TOPLAMI" ...]
```

Instead use:

```
cikti <- cikti[span == "AKTİF TOPLAMI" ...]
```

Rolling all the up, this code workds (on my system...).

```
a <- postForm("http://www.bigpara.com/analiz/mali-tablolar/",
              Yil = "2013", Donem = "4", Kur = "TL", Cins = "1", Submit = "Getir",
              HisseKod = sirket)
a <- htmlParse(a)
span  <- xpathSApply(a, "//div[@class='maliTable']//li//span", xmlValue)
span  <- iconv(span,from="UTF-8",to="")  
small <- xpathSApply(a, "//div[@class='maliTable']//li//small", xmlValue)
small <- gsub("[.]","",small)
small <- as.numeric(small)
cikti <- data.table(span, small)
cikti <- cikti[span == "AKTİF TOPLAMI" | span == "A K T İ F   T O P L A M I"] 
cikti <- cikti[order(-small)]                             
cikti <- cikti[1,]$small
```

Comment: Yeah you're right about response. I wanted to sign "* Connection #0 to host www.bigpara.com left intact" line there.

Actually, server returns a response but when I change the variable "sirket", the return doesnt change. If you enter that link and send the post manually, the table will change. But when I post that form with R, returning page is always same. Posting the form doesn't work.

Comment: I forgot to add. For example you can try "FROTO" and "FENER" to compare them. Function will return the same value but they're not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with encodings, httr and rvest handle it for you automatically:

```
res <- POST("http://www.bigpara.com/analiz/mali-tablolar/",
  body = list(
    Yil = "2013", 
    Donem = "4", 
    Kur = "TL", 
    Cins = "1", 
    HisseKod = "FENER"
  ),
  encode = "form"
)

mali_table <- html(res) %>% html_nodes("div.maliTable li")

span <- mali_table %>% html_nodes("span") %>% html_text()

small <- mali_table %>% 
  html_nodes("small") %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  gsub("\\.", "", .) %>%
  as.numeric()

selected <- span %in% c("AKTİF TOPLAMI", "A K T İ F   T O P L A M I")

data.frame(
  span = span[selected],
  small = small[selected]
)
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem:
when entered to http://www.bigpara.com/analiz/mali-tablolar/ page, default page is: Hisse: DOHOL, 2014, 9, TL, Standart which means (Yil = "2014", Donem = "3", Kur = "TL", Cins = "1", HisseKod = "DOHOL") in order to values. 

I'm changing this values in R and sending the form. But still I get the same output.
For ex. you can try to change "Yil" variable. Make it 2012 or 2011. The output will be same because post form doesn't work in that way.

Comment: Well, you need to diagnose what the browser is differently - I'd recommend learning how to use the web inspector in your browser. It's not easy to figure how a web site works when you don't speak the language.

Comment: After you said that, I tried it with PHP and it worked. When i post 2013 as "Yil" value, it returns 2013 page but in R, it is returning allways same page (DOHOL,2014,3,TL,1).
So, i think my problem is not HTML, the way doing it in R.

Comment: @Sab I doubt that - it's more likely that PHP uses different curl defaults so it gives different behaviour. Turn verbose output on in both R and PHP and compare the requests.